# Expanding a pandas dataframe based on new values of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframes called "data" and "temp_data":

[image]

"data" has columns "date_time" and "Voltage";

"temp_data" has columns "date_time" and "Temperature".

I find the absolute minimum and maximum values of the date values present in the "date_time" column between the two dataframes using:

```
min_date = pd.concat([data["date_time"], temp_data["date_time"]]).min()
max_date = pd.concat([data["date_time"], temp_data["date_time"]]).max()
```

I need to now add new rows into each of the two dataframes such that both of them start and end with the min_date and max_date in their "date_time" columns. And against each of these newly added "date_time" values, the corresponding "Temperature" & "Voltage" values in each of the dataframes can be given the value of blank/Nan.

So eventually I need the date range of the "date_time" columns of the two dataframes to be the same.

Note that all the original values present in the columns "Temperature" and "Voltage" are to be retained. Only in places where the original values are absent, they can be kept as blanks/Nan.

Can you please help me modify the two dataframes so that I can get something like this?

[image]

Comment: Please post code to reproduce the problem. Do not post images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one of the options :

```
df_ = data.merge(temp_data, on="date_time", how="outer")

data = df_[["date_time", "Voltage"]].copy()
temp_data = df_[["date_time", "Temperature"]].copy()
```

Or this :

```
df_ = pd.concat([data, temp_data])
​
data = df_.drop(columns="Temperature").groupby("date_time", as_index=False).first()
temp_data = df_.drop(columns="Voltage").groupby("date_time", as_index=False).last()
```

Output :

```
print(data)

          date_time  Voltage
0   1/30/2023 22:29     23.0
1   1/30/2023 22:44     34.0
2   1/30/2023 22:59     66.0
3   1/30/2023 23:14     45.0
4   1/30/2023 23:29     99.0
5   1/30/2023 23:44     22.0
6   1/30/2023 23:59     45.0
7    1/31/2023 0:14     78.0
8    1/31/2023 0:29     89.0
9    1/31/2023 0:44      NaN
10   1/31/2023 0:59      NaN
11   1/31/2023 1:14      NaN
12   1/31/2023 1:29      NaN
13   1/31/2023 1:44      NaN
```

---

```
print(temp_data)

          date_time  Temperature
0   1/30/2023 22:29          NaN
1   1/30/2023 22:44          NaN
2   1/30/2023 22:59          NaN
3   1/30/2023 23:14          NaN
4   1/30/2023 23:29          NaN
5   1/30/2023 23:44         22.0
6   1/30/2023 23:59         45.0
7    1/31/2023 0:14         97.0
8    1/31/2023 0:29         45.0
9    1/31/2023 0:44         65.0
10   1/31/2023 0:59         35.0
11   1/31/2023 1:14         85.0
12   1/31/2023 1:29         35.0
13   1/31/2023 1:44         77.0
```